# Update bindings from other bindings using MVVM in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to fix my problem?? I have a datagrid binded to a collection of `ModelCheckoutRecord` objects (`ListModelCheckoutRecords`). I am binding the selected item to a `ModelCheckoutRecord` (`SelectedItemModelCheckoutRecord`). In the binding for the selected item I want to update the visibility binding for another datagrid and gridsplitter (`ResponseVisibility`). The ability to update bindings from other bindings doesn't seem to work?

My XAML lines for this are as follows:

```
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <View:RowDefinitionExtended Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ListModelCheckoutRecord}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModelCheckoutRecord}" MouseLeftButtonDown="DataGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown" CommandManager.PreviewExecuted="DataGrid_DeletePreviewExecuted" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" Margin="15" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding ResponseVisibility}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ListModelResponseRecord}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModelResponseRecord}" MouseLeftButtonDown="DataGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Visibility="{Binding ResponseVisibility}" Margin="15" Grid.Row="2"/>
            </Grid>
```

The stripped down code causing me trouble is as follows:

```
    private Visibility responseVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    public Visibility ResponseVisibility
    {
        get { return responseVisibility; }
        set
        {
            if (value == responseVisibility)
            {
                return;
            }

            responseVisibility = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ResponseVisibility");
        }
    }

    private List<ModelCheckoutRecord> listModelCheckoutRecord;
    public List<ModelCheckoutRecord> ListModelCheckoutRecord
    {
        get { return listModelCheckoutRecord; }
        set
        {
            if (value == listModelCheckoutRecord)
            {
                return;
            }

            listModelCheckoutRecord = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ListModelCheckoutRecord");

            ResponseVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    private ModelCheckoutRecord selectedModelCheckoutRecord;
    public ModelCheckoutRecord SelectedModelCheckoutRecord
    {
        get { return selectedModelCheckoutRecord; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                ResponseVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                return;
            }

            else
            {
                ResponseVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }

            if (selectedModelCheckoutRecord == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedModelCheckoutRecord");
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Richard

Comment: In your `SelectedModelCheckoutRecord`, you are setting `ResponseVisibility` based on whether the selected item is null. In this case, it will probably never be null, so the visibility will **always** be visible. Rethink your logic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you truly want to have a collapsed visibility in case of `null` `SelectedItem` only, there's really no need to use code for that. The following XAML will do the job just fine.

Just give your source DataGrid a name (I've assumed Grid as name in following example) and use a style in target DataGrid like this:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="TargetGridJustToShowWhereThisGoes">
    <DataGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Grid, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Style>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks Maverik the code works fine. I've come across this issue before in other scenarios - trying to change different elements bindings from other bindings - for future reference is this possible?

Comment: As long as you can think of trigger value (only equality works) and a dependency property to set against that trigger, you can use the above pattern.